# How to re-install iOS SDK in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, install, development, ios

Xcode gives me an error when looking for iPhoneOS 8.3 SDK. The path exists in my filesystem but contains only one unrelated file. Xcode tells me I have that version already installed inside `Preferences > Components > Simulators`.

> error: There is no SDK with the name or path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk'

The question is how to reinstall the SDK to stop having this error?

Comment: Did you tried to clean remove it first with apps like AppCleaner ?

Comment: I can take a look on it now

Comment: It's a freeware version of appzapper, removes all sources of apps.

Comment: The only usage of that app would be to wipe out Xcode completely if that's that you meant. It doesn't understand the Xcode folder structure nor allow adding/removing different SDKs individually.

Comment: Yup, but as reinstalling a beta is always best to avoid problems.

Comment: After doing a reinstall the iPhone OS SDK 8.3 still appears as installed. AppCleaner did not delete the file that holds the reference...

Comment: Delete Xcode and reinstall it. The SDK is available inside the Xcode.app bundle.